# Setting the path of an exe to a variable in batch script

Tags: windows, cmd

I am trying to set the location of an exe(exe_sources/build/exefile.exe) to a variable by doing this ;

```
set script_path1=%~p0
set exe_path=script_path1\..\build\
echo exe_path
```

directory structure looks like this :

```
exe_sources
  --build
     --exefile.exe
  --runtest
    --testscript.bat
```

but I never get the correct path to the exefile.exe in exe_path.

How can this be achieved.

Comment: Just trying to understand, what is the meaning of `%~p0` ?

Comment: %~p0 gives the current location from where the script is running.So testscript.bat is the script inside the runtest folder and .exe is at some other location as specified above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In ***Linux***, for a **BASH (testscript.sh)** script:

  ```
    #!/bin/bash

    <<TREE
    exe_sources
    --build
      --exefile.exe
    --runtest
      --testscript.sh
      --testscript.bat
    TREE

    script_path1=$(dirname "$(readlink -f ./testscript.sh)"); # absolute path: /c/Users/Riccardo/Desktop/exe_sources/runtest
    B=$(basename "$(readlink -f ./testscript.sh)"); # testscript.sh
    ls "${script_path1}/../build" # exefile.exe
    exe_path="${script_path1}/../build";
    echo ${exe_path} # /c/Users/Riccardo/Desktop/exe_sources/runtest/../build
    ls ${exe_path} # exefile.exe
  ```

  You can run it in ***Windows*** too, by using the *[Git Bash](https://gitforwindows.org/)*:

  ```
    sh ./testscript.sh
  ```
- Always in ***Windows***, for a **DOS Batch (testscript.bat)** script:

  ```
    @echo off

    goto TREE
    exe_sources
    --build
      --exefile.exe
    --runtest
      --testscript.sh
      --testscript.bat
    :TREE

    set script_path1="%~dp0"
    echo %script_path1%
    ::"C:\Users\Riccardo\Desktop\exe_sources\runtest\"
    set script_name=%0
    echo %script_name%
    ::"C:\Users\Riccardo\Desktop\exe_sources\runtest\testscript.bat"
    set exe_path="%~dp0..\build"
    echo %exe_path%
    ::"C:\Users\Riccardo\Desktop\exe_sources\runtest\..\build"
    dir %exe_path%
  ```